# Typehint a list of tuples with nested tuples in python

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, typing

I'm trying to type hint the following:

```py
from typing import *

x = [('a',), (('b',), ('c', 'd'))]

f( k : list[ tuple[str] | tuple[str, tuple[str]]]):
    print(k)
```

and am unsure how to type-hint for this list.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I've updated, sorry for any confusion

Comment: `(('b',), ('c', 'd'))` doesn't match either of your types. It's `tuple[tuple[str]]`

Comment: Are you trying to specify that it can be arbitrary nesting levels of tuples of strings?

Comment: @Barmar not beyond one as indicated here, though if there was an approach to typing for multiple that might be relevant to the post.

Comment: I think the answer is: `list[ tuple[str] | tuple[tuple[str]]]`

Comment: `(('b',), ('c', 'd'))` is actually `tuple[tuple[str], tuple[str, str]]`

Answer (score 1):

Given your example, the correct annotation for a recursive data type would require a forward reference and look like:

```
Tstr = tuple[str, ...] | tuple['Tstr', 'Tstr']
```

meaning that an `Tstr` is either a variadic tuple of `str` or a nested tuple containing a `Tstr` on each coordinate.

Example inhabitants would be

```
('b',)                           # B1: base case with 1 element -- tuple[str] 
('c', 'd')                       # B2: base case with 2 elements -- tuple[str, str]
(('b',), ('c', 'd'))             # inductive case of tuple[B1, B2]
(('c', 'd'), ('b',))             # inductive case of tuple[B2, B1]
((('b',), ('c', 'd')), ('b',))   # inductive case of tuple[tuple[B2, B1], B1]
...
```

etc.

`list[Tstr]` is then a perfectly fine type hint (if its purpose is just hinting), but it won't pass type checking by mypy (see [this](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/731) issue).

If you want any of the available python type checkers to not complain, you need to settle for a simplified version i.e. set an upper boundary to the induction and explicitly specify allowed variants (e.g. `Tstr = tuple[str, ...] | tuple[tuple[str, ...], tuple[str, ...]]`).